# Heater (resistor) combination to achieve specific power

Tags: resistors, ohms-law, power-dissipation, heater

I am designing a heating circuit composed of ceramic heating resistors.
I have a 24 V supply and I am limited to 3 A, which allows me to disipate total of 70W, which is my target.

I have a limited selection of heating resistors in my disposal:
3V rated resistors: `1.8Ω 5W`, `0.9Ω 10W`, `0.45Ω 20W`
9V rated resistors: `16.2Ω 5W`, `8.1Ω 10W`, `4.05Ω 20W`
12V rated resistors: `28.8Ω 5W`, `14.4Ω 10W`, `7.25Ω 20W`
24V rated resistors: `115.2Ω 5W`, `57.6Ω 10W`, `28.8Ω 20W`

Other than that I can use any other circuit elements if it helps push me across the finish line. But most of the power must be produced by the heating resistors.

I need the heating to be evenly distributed around the perimeter of the heated area which is a rectangle. Ideally it is divided into 8 segments similar in power output. And those segments must be connected only by a single wire - therefore in series. And each segment has to be connected only to its adjacent segments. Inside each segment, anything goes (for example resistor in parallel to modify the total resistance).

I was playing with number for quite some time, but I think I overconstrained myself.

My original idea was to use 6x `3V 0.9Ω 10W` and 2x `3V 1.8Ω 5W` but when they are all in series, the `10W resistors` run only at around 6W while the `5W resistors` run at 13W, which is way above their rating.
[image: Initial atemtp]

Adding `simple resistor` in parallel to each `1.8Ω "side" heating resistor` to decrease their total resistance to 0.9Ω of course helps with the power rating but then I am exceeding my total power limit because those simple resistors disipate power as well.

Am I trying to do the impossible here? Since when I use non-equal resistors, I will always overload the lower rated resistors?

Or is there some clever way to achieve this / calculate the most efficient variant.

Comment: `area which is a rectangle` is it a square? `There are also equivalent 12V a 24V variants but I don't think they will help.` Please present them just in case - see [Sandro's solution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/660962/274544).

Comment: It is a rectangle ca 130 x 230 mm. 12V a 24V updated. Since you went full blast with solutions ... less resistors is better. Not sure of the top of my head but "long side segments" can fit 2, "short side segment" can fit 3.

Comment: Is this pure theory, or something you are actually building?  Have you looked at a temperature data sheet?  Last time I built a power resistor array, I had to 5x the size of the resistor to keep thermal limits within sanity.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. It is 100% a real thing. The heater elements are rated for 300°C and all of them are thermally bonded to a chunky aluminum container (which I am heating). It is also a closed feedback loop controled by thermostat with 30°C target. I have it running already in 60W config and those elements don't even get to a 100°C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your supply is U=24V, and you want I=3A, then you don't have the choice, your total resistance has to be R_total=U/I=24V/3A = 8ohms.

So the sum of your 8 segments needs to make 8 Ω.

So the "easiest" way to do it would be 8*1 Ω resistors (rated at least 3*3*1=9W).

The nearest thing you have, are the 0.9 Ω resistors. If crossed by 3A, they will dissipate P=R*I²=0.9*3²=8.1W (so within the 10W they accept).

If you use 8 of those resistors, you get 8*0.9=7.2 Ω total resistance. So you will overload the supply a bit (I=U/R=3.33A, and P=UI=80W)

So we need to add 0.8 ohms of resistance. To keep symmetric, lets try to split it in two, to put half of it on each "short" side of the rectangle. So we need 0.9+0.4= 1.3 Ω for the short sides.

To get close to 1.3 Ω without overrating your resistors, the best solution I found is to put three 4.05 Ω resistors in parallel, to R_eq=R/3=4.05/3=1.35

So now, you have 6*0.9 + 2*1.35 = 8.1 Ω

So the current will be I=U/R=24/8.1= 2.96A
And the total power will be P=U²/R=24²/8.1=71W

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fScyXH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or if you want each segment with exactly the same power, then the closest I can find is using 3 resistors for each segment :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAlU9a.png)</sup>

R1 and R2 in series makes R1+R2=1.35 Ω
(R1+R2) in parallel with R3 makes R_eq = 1 / (1/(R1+R2) + 1/R3) = 1/(1/1.35  + 1/4.05) = 1.0125 Ω

So if you put 8 of those blocks in series (one per segment), you get 8.1 Ω resistance, and P=U²/R=71 W

Comment: You can use `&ohm;` to get Ω in posts.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it

Comment: (if you could put 9 0.9 Ω resistors in series with zero wiring resistance, you'd get 8.1 Ω…)

Comment: true, excepted that OP wants to spread heat accross 8 segments, with "similar power" (my first solution might or not do the job because the 2 small sides seam to be different according to OP's schematics, my second solution has 8 identical segments)

Comment: Alright! You might have actually done it! Great systematic thinking. You even accidentally nailed the fact (with the first solution), that my side segments are a bit larger and most likely even able to fit the 3.

Comment: You can get by with "lower wattage" using 1.8 Ω in parallel to (1.8 Ω and 0.45 Ω in series) - at the cost of a 2.8 % deviation in power instead of 1.4 %, and driving half the 1.8 Ω resistors at their rated voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The most simply described configuration is 9 0.9 Ω resistors in series:
If one fails short, no resistor exceeds its rating. The current does (~3.3 A/79 W).
If one resistor fails open, no resistor exceeds its rating. Zero current and power.

[vir's solution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/660961/274544) has little difference in power when one resistor fails open (57 W/2.4 A), and higher current/power when one fails short (94 W/3.9 A).

Two parallel strings of 4×4.05 Ω in series give 35 W when one resistor fails open and 82 W/3.5 A when one fails short.

If some of the specifications aren't quite as hard&fast, it is easier to reach simple configurations: Assuming the choice of resistors set in stone, with negligible tolerance (8×1(.03) Ω being an obvious solution otherwise).
Using 8×0.9 Ω gives 80 W, 3.33 A@24V; 22.45V, 3.12 A@70 W (within ratings of a 75 W PS); 64.8 W, 21.6 V@3 A. (Many SMPS are adjustable, ±10 % typical)

Comment: Now, analysing geometric heat distribution is going to be "interesting" with 9 elements instead of 8.

Comment: Furthermore it does not really fit my specifications . While failing resistors are non-issue since the whole setup is behind a fuse.

Comment: It doesn't quite comply with the *ideal* segmentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV1dwZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each pair has a voltage of 6V across it, so each resistor dissipates 8.9W which is comfortably within the 20W rating and gives you some room to breathe on tolerance.  You didn't mention what tolerance each resistor has but you could add in another in series with the whole string if it ends up less than 8.23Ω once you put it all together.

Comment: Unfurtunately each segment must be connected by a single wire and each can be only connected to adjacent segments. But thanks for the answer. 